# Fill data into table having m:m Relationships

Tags: mysql, select, join, insert

There are 3 tables

```
1. Artist(artist_id,artist_name)
2. top100(track_id,artist_name)
3. Track_artist(track_id,artist_id)
```

*`artist_id`*, *`track_id`* are primary keys in their respective tables. *`track_id`* and *`artist_id`* will be referenced as foreign keys after **track_artist** table is filled with data. **Artist** and **top100** tables are filled with data.There are about 26000 rows in **Artist** table and 7770 rows in **top100** table. I have to fill **track_artist** table can anyone please help me with the query?? I am using mysql v5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
INSERT INTO Track_artist (track_id, artist_id)
SELECT t.track_id, a.artist_id
  FROM top100 t JOIN artist a 
    ON t.artist_name = a.artist_name
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe4d3/2)** demo

Comment: that is exactly I have been looking for thank you so much for the help.